# Struct type data in spark is null

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table with columns as struct data type. 
Schema of hive table:

```
-----------------------------------------  
| name        | type                         
-----------------------------------------      
| col1        | struct<                            
|             |   ccl1:string,             
|             |   ccl2:string,             
|             |   ccl3:struct<             
|             |     cccl4:strin>          
|             | >
```

in hive, output is correct

```
    select col1.ccl1 from tab  
    ccl1
    AA  
    BB
```

But same struct data type table spark:

```
    d = spark.read.table("tab")   
    d.select("col1.ccl1").show()

output in spark:  
ccl1  
null     
null  
null
```

edited: added the sample.
Any help

Comment: There might be chance that data type mismatch. Could you please provide sample data with table schema.

Comment: Check the separator to separate out struct data.

Comment: @Mugdha ..Can you please give an example